# Access VMWare OS from Android Phone through WiFi

Tags: android, terminal, wifi, vmware

I have CentOS6 installed as image in VMware, lets call this my dev environment. Host PC is running Windows 7. I've been developing websites with this setup for quite some time now.

My problem begins when I started working on themes for mobile devices. Sure I can use Chrome or Firefox's developer tools to over-ride user-agents and test the layout in a regular browser. To test in my android phone, I'll have to commit my changes and deploy the site(to staging), which is time-consuming.

I would like to able able to test my work in my android phone while it's still in my dev environment. I imagine this is quite possible, but I just don't know how.

So, here are my issues:

1. How do I access VMWare images over wifi? I have a laptop and I can't access the domain I registered in my dev environment over wifi? Is there a setting for this? Or I should be able to access it immediately but I just have problem in my laptops wifi?(which I do, btw)
2. If I'm correct, there should be a 'hosts' file in linux which I could edit to redirect a domain? How do I find this? Do I need to root my phone? If I'm not correct, then how should I be able to do this?
3. I would also like to be able to access the dev environment over ssh in my android device. I've installed a few android app, but I cannot connect to the dev environment's IP Address.